# Allowing Geolocation on a Twebbrowser in Delphi for Windows 10

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I am currently hosting an Indy 10 server that loads a page to start running the `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` function in a `TWebBrowser`. I have the registry set to run IE 11, and having the `TWebBrowser` navigate to a page to test this shows IE 11 as well. I have selected 'always allow' for the location on localhost, and visiting localhost in IE runs successfully without prompting.

However, if I have the `TWebBrowser` navigate to the page, it will never allow the geolocation to run; it is always waiting for permission. Other scripts run, and `navigator.geolocation` returns true, but it is unable to get the location.

Is there a permission that I am missing? Or any other way to make the `TWebBrowser` prompt?

The HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
<body onload="getLocation()">
<p id="loca"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var lat = 0;
var long = 0;
var x = document.getElementById("loca");
x.innerHTML = "start";
function getLocation(){
    if (navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(setLocation);
    }
    else {
        lat = 0;
        long = 0;
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function setLocation(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    long = position.coords.longitude;
    x.innerHTML = "location:" + lat + ", " + long
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

All I'm running is `Webbrowser1.Navigate('http://localhost:25566/');`

Comment: Are you doing all this just for IP geolocation?

Comment: Correct, I am then using it with some google maps but I need it to be pulled in and saved as a variable.

Comment: You may use a web service for geolocating the IP (some are free).

Comment: That's true, but since I already have this mostly working I just want to know why it isnt fully working yet